# Jetty: Websocket Events not being called

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to make a custom "http" sever embedding a `Jetty` (verion 9) into my application.

The problem I'm facing right now is that `Websocket` Events are not being called.

This is what I have to so far (relevant parts):

SocketServer:

```
public class SocketServer
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        Server server = new Server(9091);

        HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();

        ServletContextHandler sch = new ServletContextHandler();
        sch.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new RandomWebSocketServlet()), "");
        handlerCollection.addHandler(sch);

        server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
        server.start();
        server.join();          
    }
}
```

RandomWebSocketServlet:

```
public class RandomWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1134228059326523215L;

    public RandomWebSocketServlet() {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.setCreator(new AdvancedSocketCreator());
    }

}
```

AdvancedSocketCreator:

```
public class AdvancedSocketCreator implements WebSocketCreator {

    public AdvancedSocketCreator() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req, ServletUpgradeResponse resp) {
        return new Handler();
    }

}
```

Handler:

```
@WebSocket
public class Handler {

    protected Session session = null;

    public Handler() {
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {
        Log.log("WebSocket connected to client: "+session.getRemoteAddress().getHostName()+":"+session.getRemoteAddress().getPort());
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        Log.log("WebSocket error");
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        Log.log("Message: "+message);
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        Log.log("WebSocket closed: "+statusCode+" - "+reason);
    }
}
```

When I try to open a connection (using telnet, for instance), the `@OnWebSocketConnect onConnect` method is not being called.

I tried many ways, following many internet tutorials... but with no success.

Any help?

Comment: When attempting to open the connection via telnet, did you perform the complete [RFC6455 opening handshake](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-1.3)?   Including the various Sec-WebSocket-* headers?  (otherwise its not a websocket connection yet).  Try using [websocket.org/echo.html](http://websocket.org/echo.html) from a web browser instead.

Comment: Humm... I see... I thought it happens when any socket is connected. Thank you.